# How to Installing new Yii2 framework with Terminal

Tags: php, yii2

I am not able to to install yii2 which has been released on 12 oct 2014, because they are not giving yiic for install. And I don’t want to use composer.

following command does not work:

```
php yii2/framework/yii webapp appName
```

Comment: what errors do you see? does 'php -v' work? if it doens't you have to add php to your PATH environment variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check official documentaion http://www.yiiframework.com/download/

there "Install from an Archive File" section

> Download one of the following archive files, and then extract it to a
>   Web-accessible folder:
>
> Yii 2 with basic application template
>
> Yii 2 with advanced application
>   template

I don't want post these links here because they will be updated in future.